# Advice on GRANT review on MySQL servers

Tags: mysql

So I'm in for a bit of a tedious work. We have about 10 servers, each with about 4 MySQL users (plus mysql-root). All of these users have full access to their respective schema.

Now we've decided that they should only have the basic `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` rights (because that's all they need).

Looking at the `REVOKE` I get the feeling that since they've been added with `GRANT ALL ON db.*` I need to first revoke all privs, then grant the ones i need.

Now for the question. Is there a good way to do this for all users (on one server) at the same time or do I need to review them one by one?

**EDIT:**

The setup is something like this:

Server 1:

User dbuser_a with access to db_a

User dbuser_b with access to db_b
...

Server 2:

User dbuser_c with access to db_c

User dbuser_d with access to db_d
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `~/.my.cnf` file to store your MySQL password, something like this:

```
[mysql]
user            = root
password        = secr3t
host            = ...
```

Remember to `chmod 600` for it.

You can then revoke all privileges for all users with the shell snippet below:

```
mysql --skip-column-names -e 'select user,host from mysql.user;' | grep -v root | \
while read account; do
    mysql -e "revoke all privileges on db.* from '`echo $account | \ 
       awk '{ print $1 }'`'@'`echo $account | awk '{ print $2 }'`'; flush privileges;"
done
```

Do the same for granting privileges which you want.

---

**UPDATE**

You can also revoke all privileges: global, database, table, routine, ... from an user by removing the `on db.*` from the above:

```
mysql --skip-column-names -e 'select user,host from mysql.user;' | grep -v root | \
while read account; do
    mysql -e "revoke all privileges, grant option from '`echo $account | \ 
       awk '{ print $1 }'`'@'`echo $account | awk '{ print $2 }'`'; flush privileges;"
done
```

Comment: That's `revoke all privileges on db.* from USERNAME@HOST ; flush privileges;` user, by user.

Comment: Thanx for the tip. One thing though, perhaps it was not clear from my original post. On each server there is dbuser_a which access db_a, dbuser_b which accesses db_b etc. My take on your code is that it would go for several users but only one database?

Comment: Please check out my above answer.

Comment: Great work. I would never have figured that out